# Remove stopwords using spaCy from list dataframe

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I want to remove stopwords using spaCy after tokenize. But, given me an error and the error is `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'is_stop'` The data I want to do is the data after the tokenizing process which is in column named 'tokenizing'
How to fix it?

```
import pandas as pd
from spacy.lang.id import Indonesian

nlp = Indonesian()

data = [
    'Aku suka sekali beradai di wilayah yang dingin',
    'Kembali jika terjadi sesuatu di sana',
    'Sampai berapa lama kamu akan pergi dari sini',
]
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': data})
df['text'] = df['text'].str.lower()
df.head()

#Tokenizing
def tokenize(word):
  return [token.text for token in nlp(word)]

df['tokenizing'] = df['text'].apply(tokenize)
df.head()

#Remove stopwords
def stopwords_remover(words):
  return [stopwords for stopwords in words if not stopwords.is_stop]

df['stopwords'] = df['tokenizing'].apply(stopwords_remover)
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are processing a list of strings, and a string is not a SpaCy token, thus, it has no `is_stop` attribute.

You need to keep a list of SpaCy tokens in the `tokenizing` column, change `def tokenize(word)` to:

```py
def tokenize(word):
    return [token for token in nlp(word)]
```

Output:

[image]

If you need to keep `tokenizing` column filled with token texts and make `stopwords` from scratch, use

```py
def stopwords_remover(words):
    return [stopwords for stopwords in nlp(words) if not stopwords.is_stop]

df['stopwords'] = df['text'].apply(stopwords_remover)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. So, what does `token.text` mean in my code?

Comment: @teapartyyyy The text property of a [SpaCy token](https://spacy.io/api/token#attributes).